# Alternative to nested try-catch statements

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have an issue with needing a try/catch in a catch block, but am reading that this is not best practice. Is there a better way to go about this?

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc;
        try
        {
            xmlDoc = DocumentLoad(filepath);
        }
        catch (XmlException)
        {
            try
            {
                xmlDoc = DocumentLoadXml(filepath);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {                    
                throw;
            }
        }
```

DocumentLoad(string filepath) uses XmlDocument.Load(), which if it throws an exception, I try reading the file, escaping any necessary &<>"', and load using XmlDocument.LoadXml().  But that may also throw an exception.

I'm not too keen on trying to read the file first and seeing if there are invalid characters as this may not be required.

Comment: Well, you're re-throwing it, so you're fine ;)

Comment: Is the goal to go through a list of files until one doesn't throw an exception while it's loading?

Comment: Why would DocumentLoad work/fail where DocumentLoadXml doesn't work/fail? That is, why not try and immediately proceed with the "final" task?

Comment: The document is expected to load without issues, but in case there are any illegal characters in the file, DocumentLoadXml uses Streamreader.ReadToEnd(), escapes the illegal characters, and attempts  to load with the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason why you cannot do it this way?

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = null;
try
{
    xmlDoc = DocumentLoad(filepath);
}
catch (XmlException) {   }

if (xmlDoc == null)
    xmlDoc = DocumentLoadXml(filepath);
```

Comments:

- the second try/catch is eliminated because you were simply catching and throwing - if you are not doing anything with it then don't catch it
- you deliberately catch and ignore the first XmlException - this is fine, but it means we simply need to test for a null `xmlDoc` and use that as an indicator that the alternate load method neeeds to be used

Comment: I like this approach better than what I was trying.  I've done this approach several times with other code, not sure why it didn't occur to me.  Late afternoon coding with no brainpower left.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Well it's OK but the `catch {throw;}` is unneccessary - that's the default behavior:

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc;
    try
    {
        xmlDoc = DocumentLoad(filepath);
    }
    catch (XmlException)
    {
        xmlDoc = DocumentLoadXml(filepath);  // if this throws an exception it will be rethrown
    }
```

But I'm curious why `DocumentLoad` would throw an exception but `DocumentLoadXml` would not - are you trying to make the method work for both file paths and XML strings?  Seems like there's be a better way to handle that.  Could you not just inspect the data to see which method is appropriate?

Comment: "rethrown" in the comment is misleading; the nested Exception, should it occur, is simply "thrown" (only the original exception could be "rethrown" in the provided code)

Comment: In the case that there are illegal characters, DocumentLoadXml uses Streamreader.ReadToEnd(), attempts to escape those characters and then attempt to load with Xml string.  Just a contingency plan.

Comment: So why not just use `DocumentLoadXml` by default?

Comment: Just a matter of trying to avoid having to parse the entire file contents to find the illegal characters if it isn't necessary.

Comment: My point is if `DocumentLoadXml` works for all cases but `DocumentLoad` only works for some then why use `DocumentLoad` at all?  Maybe I;m misunderstanding though...

Answer (score 0):

You could move the two blocks to have them in series. This would only try the second loading method if the first didn't give you a valid document.

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = null;
    try
    {
        xmlDoc = DocumentLoad(filepath);
    }
    catch (XmlException)
    {

    }

    if( xmlDoc == null ){
        xmlDoc = DocumentLoadXml(filepath);
    }
```

Comment: If he uses that approach the second try/catch with rethrow is not necessary.

Comment: @Matthias247 it's unnecessary either way

Comment: @BabakNaffas: Yes, but if (xmlDoc == null) xmlDoc = DocumentLoadXml(filePath) would be perfectly equivalent.

Comment: @Matthias247 I agree just pointing out that it's unnecessary in the OP's method as well.

Comment: Thanks all for the help.